# Filter out elasticserach aggregation buckets with empty key

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a aggregation query like below

```
"subjectArea.untouched" : {
  "terms" : {
    "field" : "subjectArea.untouched",
    "size" : 10,
    "exclude" : "" //to exclude buckets with empty string key
  }
}
```

but the result is not as expected

```
"aggregations" : {
"subjectArea.untouched" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [ {
    "key" : "", //Not expecting this bucket
    "doc_count" : 13
  }, {
    "key" : "subjectArea",
    "doc_count" : 1
  }, {
    "key" : "test1000",
    "doc_count" : 1
  } ]
}
}
```

I don't want the first bucket in the result. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the documents with empty string in the **filter** part of the query.
For your use-case, the query would looks something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "subjectArea.untouched": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "subjectArea.untouched": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "subjectArea.untouched",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Basically the first part of the query behaves as the **WHERE** clause in sql.

**EDIT:**
To filter out **just** the buckets (without filtering out the documents), you should use [filter aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).
The query would look something like:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "filter_out": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "match": {
              "subjectArea.untouched": ""
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "subjectArea.untouched": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "subjectArea.untouched",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check.

Comment: If i add the 'must_not' filter then i will not get those documents where 'subjectArea.untouched' is empty. But I want those. What I dnt want is in the aggregation bucket with empty string key. Am i clear? Can you bring some light?

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jai. New query is giving me my expected results.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your original query is that `exclude` should get an array of values. So simply change the query to be:

```
"subjectArea.untouched" : {
  "terms" : {
    "field" : "subjectArea.untouched",
    "size" : 10,
    "exclude" : [""] //to exclude buckets with empty string key
  }
}
```

and it will work as expected.
The accepted solution seems to be overcomplicated.
[Reference here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values_2)